# Как правильно приделать домен к статическом ип адресу?

Tags: windows-7, dns, сервер

Хочу открыть трекер в интернете для своего города, вот договорился с провайдерами и получил постоянный (статический) ип адрес. Вот хочу спросить, как свой компьютер можно приделать к домену org.ua, там требует dns. Я прочитал или что-то не то или не хватает мозгов. Пожалуйста, тот кто знает, как делать пошагово объясните, как сделать это днс. И полезную информацию насчет этого. И, пожалуйста, не посылайте меня по ссылкам.
Доп.инфо
Страна: Украина
ОС: Windows 7 Ultimate x86
Знания: нулевые (учусь)

Answer (score 1):

Слова для поиска: регистрация доменов.

- [FAQ по регистрации домена org.ua](http://my-soft-blog.net/322-faq-po-registracii-domena-orgua.html)
- [Бесплатная регистрация домена ORG.UA](http://maxcoff.org.ua/web-mastering/besplatnaya-registracziya-domena-orgua.html)

Answer (score 0):

Там где покупали домен, в настройках указываете "Использовать DNS регистратора" и добавляете в панеле записи типа "А"

```
@     A    IP-адрес
www   A    IP-адрес
```

После делегирования, все запросы на www.ваш_домен.зона будут перенаправлены на ваш компьютер, далее Apache (ngnix) сделают свою работу.